# symfony2 commande in ovh cron task

Tags: symfony, cron, command, cron-task, ovh

I have to put a symfony command in a cron task. 
I'm not in a dedicated server so i have to create them from the OVH manager interface.

My problem is that i can't write command in it, only give it a file to execute.

I tried multiple solution but none are working. 
After a lot of talking with OVH support, and a lot of wrong and stupid answers from them (this support is such a shame !), i still don't understand why my cron isn't working.

What i had done, and works perfectly from a browser is that i put the following line in a php file :

```
exec("/usr/local/php5.4/bin/php app/console my:command");
```

I know it's not a great way to do it, but this is the only which work :/

The problem is that this same php file which work from a browser isn't working from a cron task.

Somebody sees an logical explanation ?

Thanks for your answers

Guillaume

EDIT

---

This is my crontab :

[image]

cronCache.php is where i put :

```
exec("/usr/local/php5.4/bin/php app/console my:command");
```

When i go to www.myurl.com/cronCache.php, the command works

EDIT 2

Solved this problem. The path to app/console was wrong and i didn't find it. I had to put something like that :

```
exec("/usr/local/php5.4/bin/php /home/my-server-name/www/app/console my:command");
```

Comment: /!\ You have a big problem with your vhost symfony conf ! The user should only have access to your `web` folder.

Comment: The user can't access other symfony folder like app or src, only the web folder and my other files that i put in my www folder, like my cron, for the moment

Answer (score 0):

Yes. If you just put `/usr/local/php5.4/bin/php app/console my:command` in your crontab, the context of execution is not in your application path but in the home of your server user.

Precisely the `app/console` folder is not in your user home but in your project. Just create a php file in your project root folder with the code you put and execute this file from the crontab

or change your command by : `/usr/local/php5.4/bin/php [your/project/path]/app/console my:command`

EDIT:

I have two more solutions:

Firstly, has your `cronCache.php` the execute right for your user on the server ? It's possible on these kind of server that only the www-data user  has this right on the www folder.

Second option:
try to change your exec command by:

```
exec("/usr/local/php5.4/bin/php ./app/console my:command");
```

to explicitely define the path.

Comment: Thanx for your answer.
My php file with my exec command is already in my project root folder.

my php file is in www/ of my ovh server.

Comment: Can we see your crontab line ?

Comment: I will try your second option and tell you as soon as i know if it works or not. Thanx again

Comment: Check the permission on the file like I said with filezilla

Comment: It was 604, just passed it to 777 to try if it's that

Comment: nothing :( damn , i really don't understand what the problem